# How to get an object using the ID of another object?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to get the `$congress` object using the ticket type *id*, so is possible to use `$congress->participants()->count`. But like this:

```
  $congress = TicketType::where('id', $id)->pluck('congress_id')->first();
  $registrationsCount = $congress->participants()->count();
```

It shows "Call to a member function participants() on integer
". Do you know why?

Comment: When did you first assign `$congress` ? Is it the first line?

Comment: did you mean `$c->participants()` or `$congress->participants()` ?

Comment: Yes, but $c only gets the id and not the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you apply the pluck function on congress_id the collection will return only the integer id, so when you call the participants on $congress you are applying a function on a integer.

If you have a relation between TicketType and Congress, then use her, like `TicketType::where('id', $id)->first()->congress;`, this should work on you next line with `->participants()->count();`.